# Ionic 2 overriding scss variables

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I tried to override Ionic 2 scss variables to make a smaller  with the following code put in my variable.scss:

```
$chip-button-border-radius: 20%;
$chip-button-size: 20px;
$chip-icon-size: 20px;
```

The API for chip can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/chip/Chip/)

HTML:

```
<ion-chip color="dark">
<ion-label>Test small chip</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

The chip didn't change.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you need parenthesis around the input `$chip-button-size:(20px);`